# How to generate correct sourcemaps for sass files with autoprefix and minification

Tags: css, sass, gulp, minify, autoprefixer

I am trying to configure gulp to convert SASS (*.scss) files into CSS, autoprefix and also would like to generate a sourcemap file for the compiled CSS file. I am trying to create two css files one normal and other minified version of it. Both of these CSS files needs to have sourcemaps. I have the following gulp config file however the sourcemaps generated by this is incorrect. When I run the gulp task without autoprefixer then everything is fine however with autoprefixer the sourcemaps is messed up i.e it points to the incorrect line number when opened up in a chorme dev tools.

I have tried multiple configurations like inline sourcemaps and separate sourcemaps. I even tried loading the sourcemaps before autoprefixing and then writing it to a file after autoprefixing is done.

```
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const clone = require('gulp-clone');
const merge = require('merge-stream');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const sassUnicode = require('gulp-sass-unicode');

const prefix = require('autoprefixer');
const minify = require('cssnano');

const {paths} = require('./config.js');

/* 
* Node Sass will be used by defualt, but it is set explicitly here for -
* forwards-compatibility in case the default ever changes 
*/
sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

sass_options = {
    // outputStyle: 'compressed',
    outputStyle: 'compact',
    // outputStyle: 'nested',
    // outputStyle: 'expanded'
    sourceComments: false,
    precision: 10
};

prefix_options = {
    browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 5%', 'Firefox ESR'],
    cascade: false
};

minify_options = {
    discardComments: {
        removeAll: true
    }
}

// Process, compile, lint and minify Sass files
const buildStyles = function (done) {
    var source = src(paths.styles.input)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass(sass_options).on('error', sass.logError))
        // .pipe(sassUnicode()) 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write({includeContent: false}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(postcss([prefix(prefix_options)]));

    // Create non-minified css file and its sourcemaps 
    var pipe1 = source.pipe(clone())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(dest(paths.styles.output));

    // Create minified css file and its sourcemaps
    var pipe2 = source.pipe(clone())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(postcss([minify(minify_options)]))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(dest(paths.styles.output));

    return merge(pipe1, pipe2);
};
```

I expect correct sourcemaps even after autoprefixing however with the current setup I am getting incorrect line numbers. (for all the styles of a child element in a nested element in the source .scss file the sourcemap points to the root element).

For instance, in the below example, when I inspect h2 element the sourcemaps points to the root element .shopping-cart (line#445) instead of (line#459)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgDIF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you call `sourcemaps.init` twice within `buildStyles` -> `source`?

`sourcemaps.init` is supposed to come before sourcemaps.write`. In your code, you have it the other way around for`source`in`buildFiles`.

Honestly, to me it just looks like your build is more complicated than it needs to be, and that is causing problems.

[See docs for reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps)

---

Also, why do you need the non-minified code if you have sourcemaps?

Comment: I am calling sourcempas.init is called for the first time before write. I am calling it again second time after compilation as per some of the online resources that I looked at. I have tried calling it only once and still had no luck.


In addition to this, the team here wanted two versions of CSS file, one minified and other regular file for better readability. So, I am cloning the pipe to generate two different versions of it and their corresponding maps.
I and our team are new to SASS and gulp and we are working on migrating CSS of a big eCommerce site into SASS.

Comment: Any suggestion in this area, is highly appreciated. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: This was our previous gulp setup but with this we were getting incorrect sourcemap line numbers. So we were trying different ways to get correct sourcemaps that would work with autoprefixer.
```

Comment: @ArjunAnkathattiChandrashekar, Just wondering, what browsers do you need to support? Back to what version of IE?